# What should be done with a dead link with no archive.org snapshot?

Tags: discussion, moderation, hyperlinks

I often sift through old questions without answers in order to find interesting material to research and answer them. Sometimes, when this happens, I will find a link that has died. In this case, I usually grab the raw link and search for a snapshot of it on archive.org. Then, when I've found a snapshot, I will edit the question and replace the old link with the new archive.org link.

Recently, I happened upon [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59155/how-does-the-catholic-church-view-penal-substitutionary-atonement/96457#96457), which refers to another question on the stack exchange site, but that link gives a 404 error. I checked out archive.org, and they had one snapshot of the page, but the snapshot was of the 404 message, so the referenced page is well and truly dead.

What should be done with these kinds of links? I put a note in the comments that the link is dead and wasn't archived. Should we remove them from the question or leave them in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link to [a question you are referring to](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59135/if-god-already-paid-for-my-sins-by-crucifixion-why-should-i-repent-now) is a deleted question.  Users with 10,000+ reputation score can see them.  In this case it's a closed question (5 years ago), scheduled deletion of type RemoveAbandonedClosed by a bot 5 years ago.

I have voted to undelete it.  When there are 2 more votes, it will be visible again.

In the meantime, just to help you answer [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59155/how-does-the-catholic-church-view-penal-substitutionary-atonement/96457#96457), here's the text of the deleted question:

> **If God already paid for my sins by crucifixion, why should I repent now?**
>
> and why am I discouraged to do more sins? Will the payment end some day? If yes, at what point? If no, its a clear injustice with those who stay away from worldly pleasures just to avoid more sins.
>
> Is all this stuff logical? Please give a logical answer, not a biblical reference! How human wit and wisdom justifies this seemingly  utterly illogical belief that Jesus already paid for all the future sins for all the world!
>
> Thanks for the guide on how to ask proper questions, I am editing it as per guidelines:
> Basically raised up in a Hindu family,  in Hinduism,  It has been never said that any of the deities died for the future generations. Especially saying that they already paid for the future sins.
>
> And I trust most Christians  do NOT adhere to this illogical belief, otherwise they would be most unlawful people in the world.

There is an extended discussion about the question [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/63266/2017/8/3).

Hope this helps !

Comment: Perhaps we should consider a process for submitting questions to be undeleted in cases like this.

Comment: @jaredad7 I know next to nothing about automated deletion and other processes by which a question / answer is deleted automatically.  I'm sure the main Meta site, [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), has more information / discussion about this.

Comment: @jaredad7 If no-one has suggested this before, maybe you could post a suggestion so that questions that were referred by a non-deleted question should be exempt from any kind of automatic deletion.

Comment: If it was auto deleted then it's likely to just be auto deleted again.